# Just created Users with Devise, want to give users their own set of objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-class

I am working on a rails application that has these classes..

> many STOCKS has..
>
> => many TIME_DELTAS

Now I just created a branch and added devise to the application. Now, I want each user to be able to have their own stock objects, not a shared database of them but user specific has their own set of stocks in their own private session.

Would I be correct in assuming to do this I would need to make the stocks a nested class of user so each user has their own stocks? Is their a guide to doing this easily? Thanks!!

**Index**

```
def index
    if current_user
     @stocks = current_user.stocks
    else
     redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
   end
    end
```

**Create**

```
def create
        # XXX Add columns for delta and current standing when we get there
        # they can intiate to nil
        # params['stock'][:user] = current_user
        @stock = Stock.new(stock_params)
        @stock.user = current_user
        if @stock.save
            redirect_to @stock  
        else
            render 'new'
        end
end
```

**Update**

```
def update
        @stock = find_stock


        if @stock.update(stock_params)
            redirect_to @stock
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
```

**Serverlog**

> Started POST "/stocks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-04 15:25:15 -0700
>   Processing by StocksController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"AvtGUf+gPXnpMHNASQK74G+f97Ho4YxkUDEfl+lhZQg=",
>   "stock"=>{"name"=>"Google", "hashtag"=>"goog"}, "user"=>"2",
>   "commit"=>"Create Stock"}   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM
>   "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
>   (0.0ms)  begin transaction   Stock Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one
>   FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."hashtag" = 'goog' LIMIT 1   Stock Exists
>   (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."name" =
>   'Google' LIMIT 1    (0.0ms)  rollback transaction Completed 500
>   Internal Server Error in 6ms
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass):
>
>   app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:21:in`create'
>
> Rendered
>   /Users/nathanielmots/.gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (0.6ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/nathanielmots/.gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb
>   (1.2ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/nathanielmots/.gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb
>   (1.1ms)   Rendered
>   /Users/nathanielmots/.gems/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (13.5ms)

Comment: What kind of relationship you expect between `User` and `Stock`. `One-to-Many` or `Many-to-Many`?

Comment: many stocks to one user

Comment: Though I may change that in the future

Comment: @KirtiThorat the changes I made to the controller are here and I keep getting 'undefined method `user' ' suggestions?

Comment: @KirtiThorat server log added

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to setup `1-M relationship` between `User` and `Stock` model, you would need to define the association as suggested below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stocks
  ## ...
end
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ## ...
end
```

After this create a foreign_key `user_id` in `stocks` table as below:

Generate a migration for adding `user_id` reference to `stocks` table by running:

`rails generate migration AddUserRefToStocks user:references`

After this run `rake db:migrate`

**NOTE:**

> *make the stocks a nested class of user so each user has their own stocks?*

There is no such thing as nested class in Ruby. What you mean probably is how to setup association between `User` and `Stock` classes.

**UPDATE**

Change your `new` and `create` actions in `StocksController` as below:

```
def new
  @stock = current_user.stocks.build
end

def create
  @stock = Stock.new(stock_params)
  if @stock.save
    redirect_to @stock, notice: 'Stock was successfully created.'  
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Also, add a hidden field (within `form_for`) in the `new` view of `stocks` as below:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that you `permit` the field `user_id` in `stock_params` method.

Comment: I'm going to ammend the controller methods to the above post, but long story short I added the field as you said and changed my controller's index to only get stocks that below to the user. However the create keeps giving me the error 'undefined method `user' ' on the create, I added it to add the field to the model it's creating but it's seems to be having problems any suggestions?

Comment: Read my updated answer and let me know. Make sure that you have defined the association exactly as suggested in my answer. Note `belongs_to :user` and NOT `belongs_to :User`

Comment: I made these changes and I'm still getting this: 'undefined method `user' for #<Stock:0x007fa962151c70>'

Comment: It's occuring on the save line of the controller

Comment: Shouldn't it be '<%= f.hidden_field :user %>' instead of :user_id

Comment: No.. because you have a field named `user_id` in database table `stocks` and NOT `user`.

Comment: It looks fine. Just run the code and let me know how it goes. Also, read the `NOTE` at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass now that I fixed elongs to

Comment: Share the server log generated with the error details in the question. You can find it on the terminal where you running "rails server". Add it in the question.

Comment: I added the server log to the above post, thanks for all your help thus far!

Comment: So this is just working now for some reason seems to be working correctly, thank you so much !!

Comment: This is bad as one could easily swap the user_id in the html and create an object for another user

Answer (score 0):

Use [Active Record Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stocks
 end
 class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :User
 end
```

Comment: So I added this, now I'm still getting when I log in as two different users the same list of stocks, shouldn't I add a column for a stock that has it's users ID then in my stocks controller only list stocks that belong to the logged in user's ID ?

Comment: Yes , you have to maintain relation.

Comment: So what I'm talking about makes sense then? I could still associate them withouthaving to nest the stocks within a user model I could still use a normal get to all the stocks and just make sure the ones being returned belong to the user?

Comment: Yes, you can associates them within a user model only no need to make nested stocks class.